# Minimizing the maximum difference between elements in array by merging adjacent elements until array reaching a specific size

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I see a lot of minimizing maximum difference between array elements by removing/inserting elements or increasing/decreasing value of elements. I thought of a variant today and have been trying to look for a solution.

Problem:
Given an array with n elements and a target size m, 1 < m < n, minimize the maximum difference between all elements by only merging adjacent elements (summing values of 2 consecutive elements to form a single element), until the size of the array reaches m.

My first intuition is

```
while(array.size() > m) 
  mindiff = difference of merge(array[0],array[1])
  mindiffarray = merge(array[0],array[1])
  for(i = 0 to array.size()-2) 
    subarray = merge(array[i],array[i+1])
    if difference of subarray < mindiff
       mindiff = difference of subarray
       mindiffarray = subarray
  array = mindiffarray
return array
```

This will work on [3,2,1,4] m = 3 -> [3,3,4],
but not [3,2,2,3,5] m = 3 -> [7,3,5] ([5,5,5] wanted)

I was thinking maybe this could be solved using dynamic programming but wasn't sure how.
Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'd start by computing the average value for the final array, and then attempt to force all values to the average. In the first example, the average is 10/3. 4 is already too high, 3 is perfect, so the only thing to do is merge 2 and 1. In the second example, the average is 15/3 = 5. So the 5 is ready and you have two ways to merge 2 and 3.

Comment: Use a priority queue which stores difference of all consecutive numbers

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841768/partition-an-array-into-k-subarrays-with-minimal-difference) answer your question?